# How to read two files and write a file with the content which matches two files and writes anothe file which doesnot match?

Tags: python, file, input

Here is my script

```
 fo1=open("foo1.txt","wt")
 fo1.write('bangalore\n')
 fo1.write("delhi\n")
 fo1.write("mumbai\n")
 fo1.close()
 fo2=open("foo2.txt","wt")
 fo2.write("bangalore\n")
 fo2.write("chennai\n")
 fo2.write("mumbai\n")
 fo2.close()
 file1=open("foo1.txt","r+")
 file2=open("foo2.txt","r+")
 FO=open("output.txt","wt")
 FO1=open("output1.txt","wt")
 x=file1.readlines()
 y=file2.readlines()
 for line1 in x:
     for line2 in y:
         if line1 == line2:
             FO.write(line1)
//write FO1 with the content which doenot match
 FO.close()
 FO1.close()
 file1.close()
 file2.close()
```

and output should be like this 
FO should have

```
bangalore
mumbai
```

FO1 should have

```
chennai
delhi
```

How to read two files and write a file with the content which matches two files and writes anothe file which doesnot match?

Comment: Are you asking us how to do this, or telling us? It seems like the code you've provided effectively does what you're asking....

Comment: What output do you expect if your input is fo1 == bangalore,chittagong,delhi,mumbai and fo2 == bangalore,delhi,mumbai? Basically what is your definition of a "difference" between files?

Comment: Edit: sorry, above comment was suppose to have the order of delhi and mumbai swapped in fo2 ==

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
FO1=open("output1.txt","wt")
FO2=open("output2.txt","wt")
one=file1.readlines()
two=file2.readlines()
for line1 in one:
    if line1 in two:
        FO1.write(line1)
        two.remove(line1)
    else:
        FO2.write(line1)
for line2 in two:
   FO2.write(line2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are fairly close. The only thing you are missing is that you need to remove the common elements from the second list and then write out the remaining items in the second list.

```
x=file1.readlines()
y=file2.readlines()
for line1 in x:
    if line1 in y:
        FO.write(line1)
        y.remove(line1)
    else:
        FO1.write(line1)
for line2 in y:
   FO1.write(line2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert x and y to set then use intersection and difference methods, see this [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects)

Example:

```
FO.write(set(x) & set(y))
FO1.write('\n'.join((set(x) - set(y) | set(y) - set(x))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x=file1.readlines()
y=file2.readlines()    
print list(set(x)&set(y))
#output =['bangalore\n', 'mumbai\n']
a=list(set(x)&set(y))
print list((set(x)|set(y)) - set(a))
#output=['delhi\n', 'chennai\n']
```